# Computation of Maximization probabilities of the EM algorithm

Tags: classification, naive-bayes, unsupervised-learning, expectation-maximization

I have implemented a semi-supervised Naive Bayes that makes use of the EM algorithm to iteratively learn from unlabeled data in a text classification problem, but I am not sure of the processing done in the Maximization step.

According to the page 7 of [this document](https://pal.sri.com/CALOfiles/cstore/PAL-publications/calo/2005/semisup-em.pdf), in the Expectation step the current classifier is used to compute the class probabilities of all the unlabeled data. And in the Maximization step, the classifier is updated using the MAP probability as the final(current) label of the unlabeled data.

Now, suppose that we got the following class probabilities for a certain unlabeled data x (text)  C1:0.75,  C2:0.10, and C3:0.15.

From the options below, how should I update Naive Bayes counts in the Maximization step?

- A) Increase C1 class count with 1, and counts of words within x for class C1 with 1
- B) Increase C1 class count with 0.75, and counts of words within x for class C1 with 0.75
- C) Increase C1,C2,C3 class counts with 0.75,0.10,0.15, and counts of words within x likewise.